# prevent sending similar posts php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to prevent users sending similar posts in my web application. 
I use similar_text function in php on my every and each row of (posts) table to calculate the similarity between two strings. 
according to this fact that I can not use MATCH and Fulltext index in my DB, what is the best fast alternate for me?

Comment: May be you your problem solved by add unique key for your database field

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods and algorithms used to find and prevent similar texts.

Check with the "adaptive local alignment of keywords" concepts.

This link might be helpful to you,

[Cosine similarity vs Hamming distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945724/cosine-similarity-vs-hamming-distance/1290286#1290286)

Comment: I said I am using php similar_text function! I wanna a method to reduce server cpu load